# Will downloaded WSUS updates be applied on shutdown if the schedule is per weekday?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Assume the following scenario:

I have a schedule specified in Group Policy for a server that says "Apply updates on Saturday at 11pm".

I approve updates in WSUS on Monday at 9am.

Updates should be downloaded some time during the week, but not applied automatically until Saturday.

If I shut the server down some time before Saturday at 11pm, will the updates that have been downloaded be applied immediately?

Edit: Also, what about a remote shutdown using `shutdown \\machinename`? I know there is an Install and Shut Down option in the UI, but what about across a few dozen servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I shut the server down some time before Saturday at 11pm, will the
>   updates that have been downloaded be applied immediately?

In my experience, no.  They'll wait until you bring them back up and apply their patches then.

As for `shutdown /s /m \\machinename`, no, according to [this question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/343120/shutdown-s-m-remotemachine-and-windows-updates).

There's an undocumented and unsupported `wuauclt /updatenow` command that might help.  There's also some info on [how to update Server Core](http://www.petri.co.il/install-windows-updates-on-windows-server-2008-r2-core.htm) that might help you script updates.

Answer (score 1):

> If I shut the server down some time before Saturday at 11pm, will the updates that have been downloaded be applied immediately?

Not unless you specify "Install Updates and Shut Down," and I'm not sure if that's an option on Windows Server OSes.

Either way, it's a silly request.  You shouldn't shut your servers down - this misses the whole point of having a server.  Restart your server after installing updates, otherwise, leave it on.

Comment: Not so silly, since the background around this question is a the fact that I've got a datacenter power maintenance operation happening during the middle of a scheduled patch window, and I'm trying to ascertain whether the servers will patch when gracefully shut down.

Comment: @Urit No, it's still silly.  Patching them and shutting them down are two completely separate events, and should be treated as such.  Set the servers to apply patches before the maintenance window, then shut them down.

Comment: Whether or not I _want_ them to patch was not asked - I am trying to find out if they _will_ patch on shutdown (probably using shutdown.exe to request them to shut down), assuming patches have already been downloaded but not installed.

Answer (score 1):

No they aren't. You need to check the option to shutdown after updates are installed.